# Client request previous webpack build's emitted files

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm having webpack include a hash in the output bundle `filename` for cache invalidation. When I push a build to production, a client that was sent an html file containing a reference to the previous build's hash will then request that file.  In the meantime, if the new build's files have replaced the old ones, those asset requests will 404.

Example:

- server contains `bundle.abc123.js`
- browser requests `index.html`, which contains `<script src="bundle.abc123.js>`
- `index.html` is sent off to the browser
- new build is pushed to prod. `bundle.abc123.js` is deleted (e.g. via `clean-webpack-plugin`. New bundle is generated as `bundle.def456.js`.
- browser receives and parses `index.html`. Browser requests `bundle.abc123.js`.
- server naturally returns a 404 response for the js file

I need to clean the `/dist` directory so I don't accumulate all the old build files. I'd like users who use the old references soon after a build goes out to still be served the old files, though.

Is there a way to clean a directory for all files older than only the one previous build? (I'd rather not move the files to a `/previous` directory and mess around with request rewrites.)

Example:

- first build creates `a.js`
- next build leaves `a.js` and adds `b.js`
- next build deletes `a.js`, leaves `b.js`, and adds `c.js`
- next build results in only `c.js` and `d.js`, and so on

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is ideal, but it's what I ended up going with. Also, I'm sure it could be done by writing a webpack plugin, but as I haven't written one before I'm implementing it in the language of the MVC framework I'm using, putting it in the startup/re-init routine. Either way, it's something you want to happen just after the `/dist` files are emitted.

- read /assets/manifest.json which will contain a list of current and previous files
- remove files from /assets listed in manifest.json > previous
- update manifest.json > previous with the contents of manifest.json > current
- update manifest.json > current with the contents of /dist
- write the updated manifest.json file to disk
- copy the contents of /dist to /assets (leaving the files currently there)

So in the end, although webpack emits its artifacts to `/dist`, all `src` and `href` references in markup refer to `/assets`, which is the real deal.  The post-webpack code I'm writing generates the `manifest.json` file and the other steps mentioned above.

This maintains the current and one previous build's files (n and n-1), all in the same folder. No rewrites or lookups needed: the files are simply maintained until the next build goes out, at which point the n-1 files become the n-2 files and are purged.

If anyone dislikes the idea of exposing older files for an extended period of time, you could move the cleanup to a process that executes an arbitrary amount of time after the build using whatever method you wish.